# How should I deploy a war file into wildfly server?

Tags: deployment, jenkins, war, wildfly-8

I'm making a CI environment using Jenkins and wildfly. I used the following command:

```
jboss-cli.bat --connect --controller=ip:adminPort --user=admin --password=*** --commands="deploy test.war --force"
```

It works fine, I can successfully access to the application after this command finished, but if I execute this command around 5 times through exec call, wildfly never respond eventually...
I'm wondering if this way of deployment is not correct. I need to find the way to deploy a war file many times. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the command slightly as below and slowness or server stop haven't happened so far (for several months)

one of big difference is not using "commands" in the new command but I'm not sure why result is different.

> /opt/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect "deploy  --force　/home/wildfly/test/build/libs/test.war"

my wildfly version is wildfly-8.2.0.Final.